# Render second element conditional when aria-hidden of first element is active

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, less

I have the following code, wherein I have the first span with aria-hidden set to true and a second span which is a normal span.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>
 <!-- Icon added visually. Voicing is suppressed. -->
 <span class="star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
 <!-- Accurate text alternative added-->
 <span>Favorite</span>
</p>
</body>
<style>
 .star:before {
 /* Icon added via generated content 
 from Unicode Private Use Area (PUA) */
 content: "f";
 }
 span.star { 
 color:purple;
 background:white;
 font-size:3em;
 padding-left:0.2em;
 }
 p>span+span {
 font-family:sans-serif;
 font-size:1.1em;
 display:block;
 padding-left:0.2em;
 } 
</style>
</html>
```

Note that the class name of the first span will be dynamic (something like "fa fa-star"), jus for now I have kept it as "star"

As of now both of these elements are getting displayed...what I actually want is whenever the first span fails to render (due to font-awesome not working or whatever reason it might be), at that time only I need the second span to show up else the second span must be hidden.

How can I do that?  Thanks in advance

Comment: why the `vue.js` tag?

Comment: that's been replaced...thanks for notifying